# Homestead command not found

Tags: macos, terminal, homestead

I am using Yosemite OSX and when I type homestead into the terminal i keep getting command not found. here is my bash_profile, what am i doing wrong?

```
export composer="php /usr/bin/composer.phar"
export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/:$composer:$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

I have also tried typing source ~/.bash_profile to reload my settings and nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Briefly: When you run this command:

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

it says something like:

```
Changed current directory to /Users/Mavericks/.composer
```

you see the PATH there. So to make your job easier add the line below to your PATH instead of yours. Remember to change this ("/Users/Mavericks") part according to yours. And be careful, there is no slash at the end.

```
/Users/Mavericks/.composer/vendor/bin:
```

Open a new terminal tab. And try this to check if it is working.

```
homestead --version
```

let me know if it is working.

Comment: This helped me. However, why is `~/.composer/vendor/bin` not working when running homestead as this user?